# SQL to check if value exists or not

Tags: sql, null, exists

I have 3 tables - `TableA`, `TableB` and `TableDetail`

```
**Table Detail**
id  FinalValue
1       99
2       88
3       77


**Table A**
id   InitValue   Num
1     10         100
2     30         200


**Table B**
id   InitValue  Num
3    20          200
```

My requirement is to get the `FinalValue` from `TableDetail` based on

```
Num
```

(`Num` value will be selected by user from a textBox UI).If TableB has a record for the partcular Num, then use Table B's id.If not, then use Table A's id.
The assumption is that Table A has records for all Num values.

For example,

```
If Num=200:
```

Since a record exists in TableB for `Num=200`, use TableB's corresponding `id (3)` and get FinalValue from TableDetail where id=3, i.e.

```
FinalValue = 77

If Num =100:
```

SinceTableB does not have any record for `Num=100`,use TableA's corresponding `id (1)` and get FinalValue from TableDetail where id=1, i.e.

```
FinalValue = 99
```

Can you plese help me frame a PL/SQL query for the same.Thanks!

Comment: Can this be solved in plain sql?

Comment: @Mosty -Yes, I would prefer it to be plain sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following, @num is passed by user

```
select FinalValue
from TableDetail
where id in
(select isnull(T2.id,T1.id)
from TableA T1 on T.id = T1.id and T1.Num = @num
left join TableB T2 on T.id = T2.id and T2.Num = @num)
```

Answer (score 3):

Replacing 200 by the value from the UI, you can do it like this:

```
declare @id int

select @id = id from TableB where Num = 200

if(@id is null)
begin
   select @id = id from TableA where id = 200
end

select FinalValue from Detail where id = @id
```